# How to get multiple containers height the same with height: auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two inline-block elements which are containers - `#keyPointsBlock` and `#caseSlider`. The block with the image will always be taller. I am wanting to match the two elements in height, so `#keyPointsBlock` needs to be the same height as `#caseSlider`. I can't change the parent element's `height: auto` to a fixed number in this situation.

Is there a way to do this?

```css
/*-- Slider Section --*/
#slideSec {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 min-height: 400px;
}
.slideSecBlock {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
}
/*- Key Points -*/
#keyPointsBlock {
 width: 40%;
 background: green;
 position: relative;
}
#keyPointsTitle {
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-size: 2rem;
 letter-spacing: .2rem;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
#keyPointsList {
 text-decoration: none;
}
#keyPointsList li {
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
/*- Case Slider -*/
#caseSlider {
 width: 60%;
 height: auto;
}
.caseSlide {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.caseSlide img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section id="slideSec">
  <div class="slideSecBlock" id="keyPointsBlock">
    <div>
      <h2 id="keyPointsTitle">Key Points</h2>
      <ul id="keyPointsList">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><div class="slideSecBlock" id="caseSlider">
    <div class="caseSlide">
      <img src="https://justifiedgrid.com/wp-content/uploads/life/biking/137646854.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you considered using flexbox for this issue? Are you firm with flexbox? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: **important note to editor** : stop clicking automatically on *tidy* !! there is a white space removed by making the div closer, tidy will screw this ... do the effort to check and test the code before and after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By simply use Flexbox and add `display: flex` to your `#slideSec` they will line up with equal high.

This works as flex children in a row direction (the default), with the `align-items` default `stretch`, will make all children on the same row be the same height, no matter which is the highest.

Furthermore, add `display: block` to your `img` so it lines up properly (w/o the white space that surrounds inline/-block elements)  and then remove all the `height: 100%` (and `height: auto` as it is the default), as that will not work well with Flexbox.

*Note, in below code sample I removed the unnecessary properties.*

If you need to control the inner elements too, better to nest Flexbox.

Stack snippet

```css
/*-- Slider Section --*/
#slideSec {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
}

.slideSecBlock {
  position: relative;
}

/*- Key Points -*/
#keyPointsBlock {
  width: 40%;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

#keyPointsTitle {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#keyPointsList {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#keyPointsList li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

/*- Case Slider -*/
#caseSlider {
  width: 60%;
}

.caseSlide {
}

.caseSlide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section id="slideSec">
  <div class="slideSecBlock" id="keyPointsBlock">
    <div>
      <h2 id="keyPointsTitle">Key Points</h2>
      <ul id="keyPointsList">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideSecBlock" id="caseSlider">
    <div class="caseSlide">
      <img src="https://justifiedgrid.com/wp-content/uploads/life/biking/137646854.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Paul You have a bottom margin set in that code (which not exist in the above) that cause that `.slick-dotted.slick-slider { margin-bottom: 30px; }`

Comment: Gotcha...missed that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use flex-box to achieve this. I made the  CSS change for `#slideSec` - added `flex` and for `.slideSecBlock` removed the height.Play with flexbox [here](https://flexboxfroggy.com/)

```css
/*-- Slider Section --*/
#slideSec {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
}
/*- Key Points -*/
#keyPointsBlock {
  width: 40%;
  background: green;
}
#keyPointsTitle {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#keyPointsList {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#keyPointsList li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
/*- Case Slider -*/
#caseSlider {
  width: 60%;
}
.caseSlide {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}
.caseSlide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section id="slideSec">
  <div class="slideSecBlock" id="keyPointsBlock">
    <div>
      <h2 id="keyPointsTitle">Key Points</h2>
      <ul id="keyPointsList">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><div class="slideSecBlock" id="caseSlider">
    <div class="caseSlide">
      <img src="https://justifiedgrid.com/wp-content/uploads/life/biking/137646854.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: row is the default value, nowrap is also the default value ... you may also get rid on inline-block, they are useless